# Awk and cut questions

Tags: bash, sed, awk

So I have a file that has to be converted to text before being read, anyways here is my dilemma.

I can do

```
$convertfile filename|cut -c39,40
```

And I'll get 2 Letters (Which is what I'm looking for but I also need to do

```
$convertfile filename|cut -c45--56
```

And get a  MAC Address that happens to be within the same line the 2 Letters above are, I need for those 2 to print on the screen.

I understand awk could help me on this one but I can't use columns because characters will continuously.

Let's say for example

```
12345:  45 45 : 12131 : XU  : MACADDRRESS1
```

I want to print `XU MACADDRESS1` and match it to the ones in `/proc/net/arp`

Now, the mac address on the file I'm converting doesn't include the ":" that are in proc net arp and I can use sed to dump the output of a grep into a text file and then match them.

Anyways, the final product would be

```
XU - IP
```

or

```
XU MACADDRESS1 IP
```

I know it's a lot of work but any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Just post some sample input and expected output. Don't tell us "MACADDRESS1", post some mac addresses.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if understood the question completely. But probably this will help:

```
> s='12345:  45 45 : 12131 : XU  : MACADDRRESS1'
> awk -F '[: ]+' '{print $5, $6, "IP"}' <<< "$s"
XU MACADDRRESS1 IP
```

Answer (score 0):

```
s='12345:  45 45 : 12131 : XU  : MACADDRRESS1'
MAC=$(awk '{print $9}' <<< $s)
IP=$(grep "$MAC" /proc/net/arp|awk '{print $1}')
```